# Redirect response from remote socket

Tags: java, sockets, http, redirect, proxy

I am trying to write a proxy in java using sockets. I am trying to have the proxy work for redirects, for example if I would like to redirect the client to another site than the one he is trying to visit, yet me code seems to fail. for example, if the user would like to enter any site I want to redirect him to google.

My code:

```
    String line = "HTTP/1.1 301 Permanent Redirect\n" +
            "User-Agent: ProxyServer/1.1\r\n" +
            "Host: " + siteDomain + "\r\n" +
            "Location: " + googleDomain + "\r\n" +
            "\r\n";
    System.out.println(line);
    try {
        writer.write(line);
        writer.flush();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: So? How doesn't it work?

Comment: @user253751, If I send this response to the client I am just getting a connection failed error.. Don't really know why it doesn't work